# How to implement client side sorting on an asp.net gridview having server side paging?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using asp.net gridview throughout my application but have got new requirement to apply sorting on each column in almost every gridview in the application. Many of the gridviews consist server side paging. I tried jquery tablesorter plugin for client side sorting and it is working fine, should it work fine with server side paged grids as i think it should be able to sort only current page records (not all the records). If yes then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In past experience, I've had a lot of trouble using out of the box Microsoft tools with jQuery, especially jQuery plugins.  Not saying it's impossible, but my recommendation would be to either ditch the out of the box microsoft tools, or use the sorting that comes with them displayed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hwf94875(v=vs.100).aspx